# How do i send keystrokes from userspace?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard

I'm writing a firefox os app to act as a game controller for linux (ubuntu precise, if it matters). The design involes the app sending messages over tcp to a server running on the user machine, and my question is about sending keystrokes from the server process to the kernel (or some layer above that). So far i've done a fair bit of research, and turned up nothing useful. I found the program `xdotool` that can do it, but the source code is rather complicated and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

See `man tty_ioctl`:

```
   Faking input
       TIOCSTI   const char *argp
              Insert the given byte in the input queue.
```